# TortoiseGitでプッシュができない

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

TortoiseGitをインストールしてローカルリポジトリを作り、適当に作ったテキストファイルをコミットすることに成功しました。

これをリモートリポジトリにプッシュしたいと思い、GitHubでリポジトリを作成し、TortoiseGitでリモートの設定を終えてからプッシュを行いました。

```
fatal: MissingFieldException encountered.
<文字化け>:
'Microsoft.Alm.Authentication.TargetUri.ActualUri'
```

[image: エラーメッセージのスクリーン・ショットです]

しかし、このようなエラーが発生してしまいました。
似たような症状の記事を探してみたのですが見当たらず、何かを試そうにも何をすれば良いのか分からない状態です。
このようなエラーの解決方法に心当たりがある方はよろしくお願いします。

## バージョン

Windows8.1
TortoiseGit 2.6.0.0
git version 2.16.3.windows.1

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　Windows のバージョンと、TortoiseGit のバージョンをご存知であれば追記して頂けませんか？　質問文の下の「編集」から自由に書き加えられます。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。追記致しました。

Comment: 関係あるか分かりませんが、つい先日 (2018年2月) Git Credential Manager for Windows から `Microsoft.Alm.Authentication.TargetUri.ActualUri` が削除されたようです ([このコミット](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/commit/34d634e70cc7a9dd11f0f18af6c6b4da23b245bd#diff-84bb57fa7b53195070c7e2a0a16d1e35L98))。私はいま Windows 環境を持っていないので再現するか試せませんが、もしかすると未報告のバグかもしれないですね。しかしTortoiseGit の[issue トラッカー](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues?scope=all&utf8=%E2%9C%93&state=all)に未だ報告されていないということは、バージョンによっては再現しないのかもしれません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。明日Windows10にアップデートして試してみます。

Answer (score 3):

`TortoiseGit`というより`Git for Windows`のバージョンの問題かもしれません。

詳しいエラー内容はメモしていませんが、自分は「Windows 7 (32bit)」「Git for Windows 2.16.2」の環境から「Git for Windows **2.16.3**」に更新したところ、コマンドを直接実行した場合でもエラーが出てgithubにpush出来なくなりました(TortoiseGit 2.6.0.0も一応インストールしてあります)。

とりあえずは一つ前の「Git for Windows **2.16.2**」をインストールし直して様子を見ています。
なお、Windows 10の環境ではgit-2.16.3でも問題無くpush出来ています。

---

**追記**

Git for Windowsの[リポジトリ](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git)で関連しそうなIssueが登録されています。

[Git for Windows 2.16.3 gives fatal: UriFormatException encountered, 2.16.2 works fine ・ Issue #1599](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1599)
[Git for Windows 2.16.3 gives fatal: ArgumentNullException encountered. 2.16.2 works fine. ・ Issue #1601](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1601)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。「Git for Windows 2.16.2」をインストールしてみたのですが、pushできませんでした。明日Windows10にアップデートして試してみます。